# Using Checkbox to Complete a Form

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to add a checkbox to my form which copies billing details from the form to shipping details, but my function isn't working.

This is what I have so far:

```
function fillShipping(f) {

    var billing = document.forms["billing"];
    var shipping = document.forms["shipping"];

    if (document.getElementById("checkshipping").checked)


    {
    f.title.value = f.title.value;
    f.firstname.value = f.firstname.value;
    f.email.value = f.email.value
    f.phone.value = f.phone.value
    f.Address1.value = f.Address1.value
    f.Address2.value = f.Address2.value
    f.city.value = f.city.value
    f.postcode.value = f.postcode.value
    f.country.value = f.country.value
    }
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: f.title.value = f.title.value;
I don't think these kind of statements do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant

```
shipping.title.value = billing.title.value;
```

Instead of

```
f.title.value = f.title.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the forms and putting them into vars why are you passing in f? why not billing.email.value = shipping.email.value? Also how are you calling this function?